# Why is Grails / Gorm looking for back reference column in DB?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

as part of an upgrade from 2.4 to Grails 5, I've encountered an oddity where when I attempt to access a particular field in a domain, I get a SQL exception because the back reference _id column is not found.

My model is as such:

```
class Parent {
  Child firstChild
  Child secondChild
}

class Child {
  static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]
}
```

My understanding is there will be a parent property added to the Child class, but no back referencing column will be created in the table unless I add a hasOne declaration to the Parent class.  Which is what I want, and what used to work.   This also works if there is only one Child, but the problem starts when I add the secondChild.

However when I have an instance of a Parent, e.g. Child childInstance and I access the parent property,  then it's firing a SQL Syntax exception  Unknown column 'parent_id' in 'field list'

Since Grails 2.4 is there something different we need to do to correctly handle this relationship and not require any parent_id in the child table

Thanks.

Comment: I have a few examples in this project that might shed some light - https://github.com/leadtrip/g522orm

Comment: @MikeW Thanks Mike,   Your Door / Handle example is pretty much what I'm replicating.    Actually in this example,  things are ok,  however see what happens if you want a door with two Handles... then that's where things have changed and it will add a door_id field to the handle table.,  I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: My gut is telling me, you should be using `mappedBy` for your case. See https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html

Comment: Thanks @injecteer that certainly looked like what I'm missing, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference, like it's being ignored.   I have a feeling it used to work but was unreliable and buggy, and they've probably changed the behaviour to address such issues.